# onBackgroundMessageHandler function is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function deployed in firebase which gets triggered whenever a document is changed and then that cloud function will send a notification to the users' device who changed it, and this is the payload:

```
const payload = (admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: "NOTIFICATION FROM CLOUD",
        body: "Sent from triggered cloud function!!",
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      },
      data: {
        title: "DATA FROM CLOUD",
        body: "Sent from triggered cloud function!!",
      },
    });
```

If the application is in the background or terminated, the onBackgroundMessage of FCM should trigger and run the callback function. The function is like this:

> **Q. Why is this function is not even running when a notification is received in the background?**

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  await _showFlutterLocalNotification(
    "HEY!!",
    "onBackgroundMessage ran myBackgroundMessageHandler()",
  );

  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

below is **_showFlutterLocalNotification()**, called inside the above function **myBackgroudMessageHandler**

```
_showFlutterLocalNotification(String title, String message) async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    "DUE_DATE_REMINDER",
    "Due date reminder notification",
    "Notification channel for task due date reminder.",
  );

  var iosChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iosChannelSpecifics,
  );

  await CustomNotificationHandler().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        title,
        message,
        platformChannelSpecifics,
      );
}
```

and this is **CustomNotificationHandler.dart** class:

```
class CustomNotificationHandler {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future initializeHandler() async {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings(
      "app_icon",
    );
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
    );
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      initializationSettingsAndroid,
      initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
    );
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    print("RAN onDidReceiveLocalNotification for IOS");
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint("Notification payload: $payload");
    }

    debugPrint("OX: DONE WITH PAYLOAD");
  }
}
```

This is my **Application.kt** to register FirebaseCloudMessaging plugin so that it runs in the background!

```
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.
            registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code block in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" 
    android:value="DUE_DATE_REMINDER"
/>
```

This is console output when the notification is sent cloud function when the app is in the background!

[image: Console output]

Have done some experiments:

1. Tried calling print inside myBackgroundMessageHandler() function, but it did not print anything in the console!
2. Tried to initialize the flutterLocalNotificationPlugin inside the _showFlutterLocalNotification()